# use dns instead of ip address windows static route add

Tags: windows, route, static-routes

I need to add some static route with this command on a Windows command prompt:

```
ROUTE ADD -p IPADREESS GATEWAYIP
```

But what I want is to use Dns instead of Ip address  Is there a way ? How ?

For example:

```
ROUTE ADD -p *.example.com GATEWAYIP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first resolve the IP address of destination domain by `nslookup` or similar tool, and then use the IP address to add the route.

One cannot setup dynamic routing based on DNS names. It is always performed with IP addresses.